# Get historical Floor price, Volume, MCAP, Holders of an NFT collection like Opensea

Tags: api, blockchain, nft, opensea

I used this API for getting information of an NFT collection.
https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/doodles-official

```
"stats": {
            "one_day_volume": 269.02799999999996,
            "one_day_change": 0.1767474411687516,
            "one_day_sales": 20.0,
            "one_day_average_price": 13.451399999999998,
            "seven_day_volume": 3036.259524641884,
            "seven_day_change": 0.6545155099925972,
            "seven_day_sales": 243.0,
            "seven_day_average_price": 12.494895163135325,
            "thirty_day_volume": 15225.684625068709,
            "thirty_day_change": -0.5598798202705255,
            "thirty_day_sales": 992.0,
            "thirty_day_average_price": 15.348472404303134,
            "total_volume": 84892.78728497593,
            "total_sales": 19611.0,
            "total_supply": 10000.0,
            "count": 10000.0,
            "num_owners": 6107,
            "average_price": 4.3288352090651125,
            "num_reports": 8,
            "market_cap": 124948.95163135325,
            "floor_price": 12.39
        }
```

It returns now state stats of the collection.
I hope to get historical values to make a chart like the below image.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I just want to know what API can I use to get the historical data of a collection.

Comment: There isn't one, but there's one for historical listings so you can try to figure floor out from that.

Comment: You mean Opensea Events API?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: So you mean, I need to analysis the opensea events api?

Comment: I know that that already but it's takes so much to do that so I was looking for a supports...
But if it's true, I will follow your opinion. Really Thank you

Comment: @LuckyArthas did you end up parsing the opensea events...?